# Python Group by a column and count string in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to count how many 'AA' in column 'type', group by 'card' column

sample data

```
index   card    type
0       88       AA
1       88       AA
2       88       dsv
3       44       AA
4       44       AA
5       44       AA
6       44      yoyp
7       44      yoyp
```

expected output

```
card type
88    2
44    3
```

my approach will work, but I want to learn a better way of doing it

```
d= df[df.type== 'AA']
```

Then i use groupby

```
d.groupby(['card']).type.count()
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `df.loc[df.type == 'AA', 'card'].value_counts()`? Struggling to find a duplicate but this question feels like a common one.

Comment: your answer is right

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use groupby,

```
 df.loc[df['type']=='AA'].groupby('card')['type'].agg({'count'})
 #output
       count
  card  
  44    3
  88    2
```

Answer (score 0):

good answer from user @miradulo

```
df.loc[df.type == 'AA', 'card'].value_counts()
```